# R partial sums after group by using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, count, sum

I am trying to calculate a total sum (based on a variable) for a partial sum (based on two variables) for a given condition in a group by. Is that possible to do it using dplyr to retrieve all the values in same view?

**Input data:**

```
view(df %>% 
     group_by(order, type) %>% 
     summarize(total_by_order_type = n(),
               total_by_order = n())
    )
```

```
|order|type|total_by_order_type|total_by_order|
|1    |A   | 5                 | 5            |
|1    |B   | 7                 | 7            |
|2    |A   | 2                 | 2            |
|3    |A   | 10                | 10           |
|3    |B   | 6                 | 6            |
```

**Output needed:**

What i need is that column "total_by_order" retrieve the total by order, meaning the sum of "total_by_order_type" by order

```
|order|type|total_by_order_type|total_by_order|
|1    |A   | 5                 | 12           |
|1    |B   | 7                 | 12           |
|2    |A   | 2                 | 2            |
|3    |A   | 10                | 16           |
|3    |B   | 6                 | 16           |
```

Comment: It's really helpful if you are able to provide a runnable R example of the input data, the `dput` function is really useful for this. The example data only needs to be a few rows, such as `dput(head(mtcars))` and then copy and paste the output  
The [repex](https://reprex.tidyverse.org/articles/reprex-dos-and-donts.html) R package is also useful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One easy way is to create the observations counts separately and then join.
Assuming you want the number of observations of order and type, not a sum of a value as you are using `n()` in your `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)

data <- data.frame(
  "order" = c(1,1,2,3,3),
  "type" = c("A", "B", "A", "A", "B"),
  "value" = c(7,2,8,3,5)
)

order_type <- data %>%
  group_by(order, type) %>%
  summarise(total_by_order_type  = n()) 

order <- data %>%
  group_by(order) %>%
  summarise(total_by_order  = n()) 

order_type %>%
  left_join(order, by = "order")
```

If you don't want row counts but the total sum of a column then swap `n()` for `sum`

```
order_type <- data %>%
  group_by(order, type) %>%
  summarise(total_by_order_type  = sum(value) )

order <- data %>%
  group_by(order) %>%
  summarise(total_by_order  =  sum(value)) 

order_type %>%
  left_join(order, by = "order")
```

Answer (score 1):

Thank you all.
The following code is what I was trying to replicate

```
data <- data.frame(
  "order" = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3,3),
  "type" = c("A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B","B","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A","B","B","B","B","B","B")
)

total_by_order_type <- data %>%
  group_by(order, type) %>%
  summarise(total_by_order_type  = n()) 

total_by_order <- data %>%
  group_by(order) %>%
  summarise(total_by_order  = n()) 

view(
  total_by_order_type %>%
    left_join(total_by_order, by = "order") %>% 
    mutate(percentage_per_order = paste(round(total_by_order_type/total_by_order*100,digits=2),"%",sep=""))
)
```

**Output:**

```
|order|type|total_by_order_type|total_by_order|percentage_per_order|
|1    |A   | 5                 | 12           |41.67%              |
|1    |B   | 7                 | 12           |58.33%              |
|2    |A   | 2                 | 2            |100%                |
|3    |A   | 10                | 16           |62.5%               | 
|3    |B   | 6                 | 16           |37.5%               |
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the group_by twise. First you group by the "type" column, take the count then do another group_by on "order" column.

```
df %>% group_by(type) %>% 
mutate(total_by_order_type = n()) %>% group_by(order) %>% 
mutate(total_by_order=n()) %>% ungroup()
```

Comment: Does this work? If you `group_by` type then order does not exist to later group by?
In my repex it doesn't work, have you got an example of it working? 
I get the error `! Must group by variables found in .data.`

Comment: Sorry, instead of summarise, use the mutate function.

Comment: Are you able to provide an [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) ? :)

Comment: df<- data.frame(x=c("A","B","A","B","B"),y=c(1,1,1,1,2),value=c(100,200,20,30,40))

Comment: df %>% group_by(x) %>% mutate(x_total=sum(value)) %>% group_by(y) %>% mutate(y_total=sum(value)) %>% ungroup()